# Unable to connect to wifi my dell xps13

Tags: networking

My dell laptop is xps13, card type is dw1560, but can't find this type of Linux network card.

Machine type is XPS13D - 9343-9343.
[image: This is my photo]

Comment: Please [run the WiFi diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Comment: My computer can't use cable network, cannot use the Internet, can't diagnosis, I think there should be no this type of network card driver

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version ?

Comment: +1 for taking a photo of the screen instead of a screenshot :-)

Comment: @yangyao: You can still download the diagnostic script, save it onto a USB drive and run it in your Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use either an Ethernet USB adapter or a Wi-fi dongle to connect to internet to install the needed driver.

Once you are connected to internet, run :

```
 sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```